# Scroll view with fixed background - Android

Tags: scrollview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to make a scroll view of 15 buttons in it, with a background but the problem is that the background image will also scroll with the buttons. need fixed background with only contents scrollable is it possible? or atleast can i make a loop of background (symmetric image) so no one can notice

Comment: Any failing code to show us?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have set background image at ScrollView instead of parent LinearLayout. Try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/background"
 >
    <ScrollView 
    ...>
        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon"
        ... />
    </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's not working bro. It says scroll view inside a relative layout is useless

Comment: just suppres the warning and try and run in mobile phone

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/rel"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scroll" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    
    

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
  >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/eee"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/eee"
         android:textSize="50sp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button11"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button6"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button7"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button8"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button9"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button10"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

 </LinearLayout></ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

this worked for me